# Merge row with a same column value based on other column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe which looks something like this:

```
data = {'Id':["A", "A", "A", "B", "B","B"], 
    'extraction': ["apple", "cherry", "alfatoxin", "ethyl", "glyphosate", "pasta"],
     "entities": ["food", "food", "hazard", "hazard", "hazard", "food"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    Id  extraction   entities
 0  A   apple        food
 1  A   cherry       food
 2  A   alfatoxin    hazard
 3  B   ethyl        hazard
 4  B   glyphosate   hazard
 5  B   pasta        food
```

The output that I would like to have is:

```
    Id  food               hazards
 0  A   [apple, cherry]    alfatoxin
 1  B   pasta              [ethyl, glyphosate]
```

How can I do this in pandas? is groupby a good option here?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) with aggregation as `list`:

```
df.pivot_table(index='Id', columns='entities', values='extraction', aggfunc=list)
```

Output:

```
entities             food               hazard
Id                                            
A         [apple, cherry]          [alfatoxin]
B                 [pasta]  [ethyl, glyphosate]
```

Alternatively, to have single items not as list:

```
df.pivot_table(index='Id', columns='entities', values='extraction',
               aggfunc=lambda x: list(x) if len(x)>1 else x.squeeze())
```

Output:

```
entities             food               hazard
Id                                            
A         [apple, cherry]            alfatoxin
B                   pasta  [ethyl, glyphosate]
```